# How can I disable the fade in and fade out effects in pgAdmin 4 when opening windows?

Tags: pgadmin

Is there any way to disable the fade in and fade out effects in pgAdmin 4 when opening windows?

Example of fade in and fade out:

[image]

Comment: Is there a place we can go to vote to get rid of this abomination of a UX?

Comment: @DavidMurdoch if you find, please let me know!

Comment: @DavidMurdoch: https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/

Comment: I really want to +1 this for the little mouse pirouette you do when homing in on the blue button...

Comment: @Jerb pgAdmin 4 being into useless, time-wasting visual effects, I thought it'd be appropriate I do the same :)

Answer (score 4):

I could not disable the fade completely, but I got to remove the zooming effect (which also executes faster) improving the user experience. The zooming effect is added by [AlertifyJS](http://alertifyjs.com/).

Edit the file `alertify.pgadmin.defaults.js` file located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v1\web\pgadmin\static\js`

Then change

```
alertify.defaults.transition = "zoom";
```

to

```
alertify.defaults.transition = "fade";
```

After making these changes, restart pgAdmin4 or click on File > Reset Layout.

Hopefully this step assists someone to find a better solution...

One can also set the above option to `none`, in this case it seems to default to the pulse transition.

Answer (score 2):

It's now available in pgAdmin 4 Preferences (at least since 4.14).

1. File -> Preferences.
2. Display section.
3. Switch "Enable dialogue/notification animation?" to false.

It works way better without animation when working remotely

You can also disable tree animations separately.

See more in docs:
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/preferences.html